# Import CSS in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, css

Is the following proper ECMAScript?

```
import * as css from './app.css';
```

If it is not, is it going to be?

Many web frameworks use this syntax to explicitly import CSS instead of doing it implicitly with a bundler (e.g. `MyComponent.css` is obviously the style of `MyComponent.js`).

What are the advantages, considering also that we can already import a CSS file inside another CSS file.

Comment: What would be the meaning or the point of importing CSS into a JavaScript module?

Comment: @Pointy Adding style to the component.

Comment: JavaScript is JavaScript and doesn't necessarily have anything at all to do with a DOM or its rendering.

Comment: @Pointy I'm talking about ECMAScript

Comment: I believe you just answered your own question. This is not ECMAScript, and is custom syntax some bundlers such as Webpack can use, and some do it to pass CSS content to web components.

Comment: @Isar same thing really

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I just want some confirmation because I'm seeing this syntax everywhere.

Comment: @Pointy I consider JavaScript just the language while ECMAScript the specification for the use of this language on the browser.

Comment: That is not accurate.

Comment: ECMAScript is the language specification, JavaScript is a dialect or family of dialects that follow said specification. However, neither of those words are specifically about browsers.